# how to remove duplicates in a string, for example: "my name is this and that this and that"- the output would be "my name is this and that"

Tags: java, string

i have tried this

public static void duplicateRemover(){
//removes all the duplicate words in a string from the user

```
//ask the user to enter his/her input
System.out.println("Enter your sentence: ");

//get user input
Scanner string = new Scanner(System.in);
String UserInput  = string.nextLine();

//add comas into string and create an array
String[] arrayString = UserInput.split(",");

System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arrayString));

//create a new array that stores the non duplictes
String[] newArray = new String[arrayString.length];
Arrays.asList(newArray);
    
//loop through array to find duplicates
for (int i = 0 ; i < arrayString.length; i ++){
 for (int j = 0; i < arrayString.length; i ++){
    //try to remove duplicates
 if (i != j){
```

//this is tha part i am struggling with, how would i removes a duplicate after looping through he array

```
 String a = Integer.toString(i);
  String b = Integer.toString(j);
  
  newArray.add(a);
 
 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the easier way:

```java
    List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(source.split("\\s"));
    Set<String> distincts = new LinkedHashSet<>(arr);
    String result String.join(" ", distincts);
```

Rewriting above using Java 8 streams

```java
    public void duplicateRemover() {
        String source = "my name is this and that this and that";
        List<String> distincts = Arrays.stream(source.split("\\s")).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        String result = String.join(" ", distincts);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Array  It will work**

```
public class RemoveDuplicateInArrayExample{  
public static int removeDuplicateElements(int arr[], int n){  
    if (n==0 || n==1){  
        return n;  
    }  
    int[] temp = new int[n];  
    int j = 0;  
    for (int i=0; i<n-1; i++){  
        if (arr[i] != arr[i+1]){  
            temp[j++] = arr[i];  
        }  
     }  
    temp[j++] = arr[n-1];     
    // Changing original array  
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++){  
        arr[i] = temp[i];  
    }  
    return j;  
}  
   
public static void main (String[] args) {  
    int arr[] = {10,20,20,30,30,40,50,50};  
    int length = arr.length;  
    length = removeDuplicateElements(arr, length);  
    //printing array elements  
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)  
       System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");  
}
```

}